# Vue: issue applying class when element is not in view

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to apply a class to a DOM element only when this element is in view inside my viewport (any part of it appearing on screen), however my console log says it's always not in view so the css class is not being applied. For this purpose I'm using a vue directive and a scroll event listener, here is my directive:

```
Vue.directive('focus-toggle-class', {
    isLiteral: true,
    inserted: (el, binding, vnode) => {

        let scrolled = false;
        let rect = {};

        let checkInView = function(){
            if (inView) {
                el.classList.add(binding.value);
                console.log('in view');
            }
            else{
                el.classList.remove(binding.value);
                console.log('not in view');
            } 
        };

        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
            console.log(rect);
            checkInView();
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
                scrolled = true;
            });
        });

        let inView = (
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
        )

        let timeout = setInterval(function() {
            if (scrolled) {
                scrolled = false;
                checkInView();
            }
        }, 2000);

    }
});
```